# Exception not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, exception, xhtml

I have been reading through the W3Schools tutorials on JavaScript, and am having a hard time understanding why my script is not throwing an exception. I expect it to throw an exception on the call document.getElementById("paragraphs"), because there is no id that equals paraghraphs. Please let me know why it's not throwing an Exception?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Design Patterns</title>
</head>

<body>  

<button type="button" onclick="throwException()">Click Me!</button> 
<p id="paragraph">I am a paragraph</p>

<script>

function throwException(){

try{            
        var errorContainer = document.getElementById("paragraphs").value;               
}catch(err){            
        errorContainer.innerHTML="An error occured...";
        }
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _I have been reading through the W3Schools tutorials_ -- that's your first mistake. :)

Comment: Try replacing `throw "Hey I'm an exception!";` with `throw new Error("Hey I'm an exception!");`let me know if this helps... :)

Comment: There's no variable `error` in the `catch` block. Did you mean `err`?

Comment: I was starting to wonder if W3Shools was sufficient, seems like it leaves all the real details out :)

Comment: `getElementById()` doesn't throw an exception when it can't find the ID, it just returns `null`.

Comment: @renatoargh You can throw a string, it creates an exception whose value is the string.

Comment: Stupid question... I was trying to use a catch block to set an element's text that was never found! If I simply create an alert in the catch block it works fine...I will give everyone an up vote since your answers did help.

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure about it in the browser, but in nodejs this implies loss of information in the stacktrace afaik

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't throwing an exception on `var error = document.getElementById("paragraphs");` because `document.getElementById()` does not throw an exception when the element is not found, instead it returns `null`. [Check this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) under the "Notes" section.

Also, as indicated in a comment above, W3Schools is not a great resource. It is good for purely beginner activities to learn the very basics, but beyond that it is known to the wider community as a source of bad coding practices and sometimes just plain misinformation.

A much better documentation resource (it doesn't have tutorials, but has much better documentation, at least on Javascript) is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org).